# Selenium (c#) - No unique identifiers in html elements - javascript?

Tags: c#, selenium

I've been asked to write a script that will run through a list, and check off some checkboxes, according to some pre-defined criteria. I didn't think this would be too much of a problem since I've had good success with Selenium in the past. But now...

The site has a list, and each item in the list has a checkbox in front of it. Check off the box, click "save", and voilà.

Except that when I inspect the element, I get this HTML:

```
<span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="vm.selectedOrganizations[node.id]"   data-ng-disabled="::!vm.canUpdateOrganizations" 
                    class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched">
        <i class="tree-organizations-icon"></i>
        <div tree-expand-item="">
            <span nx-render-organization="::node" ng-click="">
                <span>
                    <a data-ng-class="{'text-muted': !organization.active}" href="">List Element Text</a>
                    <small>
                        <!---->
                        <!---->
                        <!---->
                        <!---->
                    </small>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </span>
```

The HTML is IDENTICAL for every single list item - the only difference being "Name of List Item", and "ng-not-empty", which is "ng-empty" for the unchecked items.

I can find nothing that is connecting the checkbox to the text and know of no way to click "the checkbox that is next to the text: "Foo".

Is it because all of the "fun" stuff is happening server-side or...?

Any ideas on how I can "grab" the elements I need?

Comment: If i'm wrong about the '</span>'  (i think  i might be now i look again) in the middle that needs to be closed let me know - i just need you to format the html so it's easier to read... Stick it in here https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/ and press beautify - then just make sure the tags are all closed and as expected :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the xpath `parent` function to move up the DOM from a fixed anchor/position.

Try identifying your checkbox this xpath:  [updated for new html]

```
//a[text()='List Element Text']/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/input
```

This xpath finds your fixed position, goes up to the parent 4 times then down to the input checkbox.

It's a simple one - but it's not the best solution (it's a bit ugly and potentially fragile).

More info on the xpath axes are available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes).

If this is still giving you trouble just let me know. There is going to be a scripted solution for this which involves getting all objects. But - a simple xpath can mitigate this complication so we should try it first.

[Another quick update]:
An alternative xpath that's a bit shorter:

```
//a[text()='List Element Text']/preceding::input[1]
```

Find the text then get the first input preceding it.

---

[Another Another Update]
The question is answered but i mentioned in the comments a coded approach to get all objects + a linq query to select the one we want by text.

If it's of any use yo anyone looking for it, this is a working solution:

```cs
        [Test]
        public void StackOverflow_IterateInputs()
        {
            //setup
            var driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Url = @"c:\git\StackCheckBoxes.html";

            //Get all the checkboxes  PARENTS - the anchor with the text is not a child of the input, it's a child of the parent.
            var listofParents = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//body/span"));

            //This is how to identify check boxes inside the parent
            string checkBoxCss = "input[type='checkbox']";

            //Use it like this
            var parent = GetObjectFromChildAnchorText(listofParents, "List Element Text");
            parent.FindElement(By.CssSelector(checkBoxCss)).Click();

            //Use it like this again!
            var anotherParent = GetObjectFromChildAnchorText(listofParents, "Text 3");
            anotherParent.FindElement(By.CssSelector(checkBoxCss)).Click();


            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
        }

        public IWebElement GetObjectFromChildAnchorText(ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> listOfParents, string text)
        {
            //return the first IWebElement where the relative [a] tag contains the text we're looking for
            return listOfParents.FirstOrDefault<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a")).Text == text);
        }
```

The concept is to get all the top-parent span(s) with `By.XPath("//body/span"));`, identify which one is the right one by checking the the `a` contains the text, then get the input related to it.

In the code I reference a local file `@"c:\git\StackCheckBoxes.html";`

For this to run - i used the following HTML. This is the source block posted in the question and duplicated 3 times to create a non-ID, non-unique block of checkboxes with different text to select...

```html
<html><body>

<span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="vm.selectedOrganizations[node.id]"   data-ng-disabled="::!vm.canUpdateOrganizations" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched">
        <i class="tree-organizations-icon">
        </i>
        <div tree-expand-item="">
            <span nx-render-organization="::node" ng-click="">
                <span>
                    <a data-ng-class="{'text-muted': !organization.active}" href="">List Element Text</a>
                    <small></small>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
</span>

<span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="vm.selectedOrganizations[node.id]"   data-ng-disabled="::!vm.canUpdateOrganizations" 
                    class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched">
        <i class="tree-organizations-icon"></i>
        <div tree-expand-item="">
            <span nx-render-organization="::node" ng-click="">
                <span>
                    <a data-ng-class="{'text-muted': !organization.active}" href="">Text 2</a>
                    <small></small>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
</span>

<span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="vm.selectedOrganizations[node.id]"   data-ng-disabled="::!vm.canUpdateOrganizations" 
                    class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched">
        <i class="tree-organizations-icon"></i>
        <div tree-expand-item="">
            <span nx-render-organization="::node" ng-click="">
                <span>
                    <a data-ng-class="{'text-muted': !organization.active}" href="">Text 3</a>
                    <small></small>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
</span>

</body>
</html>
```

End result is two checkboxes ticked:

[image: checkboxes tickedd]

Comment: Ok the answer sounds good - thanks for the xpath link. I haven't had to use them much so far so the reference is good.
There wasn't a typo - just a slew of spans and divs since this is only one element of MANY so I manually closed some, might have made a typo at the end there...

Comment: I'm still playing with this :-)  -  where does the `<input>` close?    - at the moment the spans and text are all children of it. IS that right?    - when i duplicate the code to create 2 boxes (but change the text), this is an option (but is a bit ugly)  `//a[text()='Name of List Item2']/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/parent::*/input`

Comment: I updated the HTML in the original post - should be much easier to read?

Comment: updated the xpath accordingly.  if you need the coded solution let me know. I suggest you use your strengths though - if you're good at xpaths use that, if you good at c# we can use that... c# will be find elements to get all inputs, then inside those, use a linq to pull out the element that has the right a[text() ... ]  - simple in theory, right? :-)

Comment: Hehe the theory is always easy :D - Thanks for your help Rich!!